# Concatenate numpy arrays to two arrays using pandas, numpy or other

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series of numpy arrays generated for example like this:

```
import random
N = 5
data = [[random.random() for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
names = ['a','b','c','d','e']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = names
```

ie:

```
a    b    c    d    e
0.01 0.03 0.01 0.2  0.04
0.2  0.01 0.02 0.01 0.1
...
```

and I would like to format it so that it looks like this:

```
name    value
a       0.01
b       0.03
c       0.01
d       0.2
e       0.04
a       0.2
b       0.01
....
```

(order of data is not important)

I have tried pandas dataframe transpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = names
```

but the result looks like this:

```
a    0.1   0.2  0.01 0.2
b    0.3   0.1  0.2  0.01
....
```

Any idea on how to reformat the numpy arrays/pandas dataframe to have two columns of data?

Comment: code that generates "data" is incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeat column names and [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for flatten values of `DataFrame`:

```
#random dataframe
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
3  4  0  9  6  2
4  4  1  5  3  4
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "name": np.tile(df.columns, len(df.index)),
        "value": df.values.ravel()})
print (df2)        
   name  value
0     A      8
1     B      8
2     C      3
3     D      7
4     E      7
5     A      0
6     B      4
7     C      2
8     D      5
9     E      2
10    A      2
11    B      2
12    C      1
13    D      0
14    E      8
15    A      4
16    B      0
17    C      9
18    D      6
19    E      2
20    A      4
21    B      1
22    C      5
23    D      3
24    E      4
```

**Timings** (`len(df) = 1M`):

```
#random dataframe
np.random.seed(100)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,5)), columns=list('abcde'))
print (df)

In [86]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame({"name": np.tile(df.columns, len(df.index)),"value": df.values.ravel()}))
10 loops, best of 3: 84.8 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((np.tile(df.columns, df.shape[0]), df.values.reshape(-1,1))), columns=['name', 'value']))
10 loops, best of 3: 196 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit (df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'index':'name'}))
1 loop, best of 3: 344 ms per loop
```

If need output `numpy array` add [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
print (np.column_stack((np.tile(df.columns, len(df.index)), df.values.ravel())))
[['a' 8]
 ['b' 8]
 ['c' 3]
 ['d' 7]
 ['e' 7]
 ['a' 0]
 ['b' 4]
 ['c' 2]
 ['d' 5]
 ['e' 2]
 ['a' 2]
 ['b' 2]
 ['c' 1]
 ['d' 0]
 ['e' 8]
 ['a' 4]
 ['b' 0]
 ['c' 9]
 ['d' 6]
 ['e' 2]
 ['a' 4]
 ['b' 1]
 ['c' 5]
 ['d' 3]
 ['e' 4]]
```

Comment: Nice solution! scales well too. But do note that `np.column_stack` doesn't preserve the dtypes.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.791796  0.428642  0.887860  0.803709  0.860545
1  0.230401  0.105232  0.617007  0.557678  0.590459
2  0.448462  0.314422  0.207188  0.785642  0.022271
3  0.075631  0.707029  0.111538  0.769387  0.174297
4  0.707566  0.299966  0.197642  0.145841  0.231135

In [12]: df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
Out[12]:
   index         0
0      a  0.791796
1      b  0.428642
2      c  0.887860
3      d  0.803709
4      e  0.860545
5      a  0.230401
6      b  0.105232
7      c  0.617007
8      d  0.557678
9      e  0.590459
10     a  0.448462
11     b  0.314422
12     c  0.207188
13     d  0.785642
14     e  0.022271
15     a  0.075631
16     b  0.707029
17     c  0.111538
18     d  0.769387
19     e  0.174297
20     a  0.707566
21     b  0.299966
22     c  0.197642
23     d  0.145841
24     e  0.231135
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `concat` all the columns in `df` together. Since columns' name are different, you need to set them with the same name. If not, `pandas` will add new columns into the `concat` result.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

N = 5
data = [[random.random() for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
names = ['a','b','c','d','e']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = names
df = df.transpose()
print df

#           0         1         2         3         4
# a  0.643042  0.061476  0.415979  0.209272  0.394414
# b  0.175363  0.580336  0.056173  0.468121  0.388956
# c  0.096257  0.570860  0.516667  0.892087  0.956790
# d  0.082906  0.340805  0.466074  0.010123  0.293006
# e  0.430240  0.759413  0.083779  0.442159  0.434603

df_col=[df[[i]] for i in range(len(df))]    # separate columns in df
for col in df_col:
    col.columns=['value']                   # change the columns' name

res = pd.concat(df_col)                     # concat them all together
res.index.names=['name']

print res

#          value
# name          
# a     0.643042
# b     0.175363
# c     0.096257
# d     0.082906
# e     0.430240
# a     0.061476
# b     0.580336
# c     0.570860
# d     0.340805
# e     0.759413
# a     0.415979
# b     0.056173
# c     0.516667
# d     0.466074
# e     0.083779
# a     0.209272
# b     0.468121
# c     0.892087
# d     0.010123
# e     0.442159
# a     0.394414
# b     0.388956
# c     0.956790
# d     0.293006
# e     0.434603
```